# Magento - Quickly translate catalogue/product info

Tags: php, magento

I created a store view for each language and installed the necessary language packs. I know how to create a product and then switch store view to translate its name/description.

The problem is that this process is very slow in case I need to insert a lot of products. 
So my question: is there any way to do it faster (such as using translation files or being able to insert names/descriptions all in one page)?

Comment: what you want is called MAGMI

Answer (score 0):

Magento does use files for localization (app/locale). With these files, you can translate almost anything except the product description and CMS pages. You have to create different description for each language. For one product is fine, but not when you have thousands of products.

If you have a lot of products, you may want to try an extension.

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-translate.html

Comment: That isn't what I was looking for, but it might be a useful complement to manual translations. Thank you.